# Issue with SSRS and Sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I am adding a **SQL Server Reporting Service Report Viewer Webpart** onto a webpart page and i place a report generated using [SSRS](http://sharepointtaskmaster.blogspot.in/2011/08/make-report-by-reporting-service-with.html) in the document library. I have two reports one with no parameter and one with user parameter.

The one without user parameter works fine on sharepoint webpart but when i try to add report the one with parameter to a report-viewer webpart i get the following issue

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
An attempt has been made to use an unregistered data extension, 'XML'. To use this data extension, it must be registered in the Web.config file of this Web application.
```

Refer the Image below.
[image]

**NOTE: The DatatSource connection is of type XML as i am using webservice to fetch the data.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not because of the Parameters, the issue is because the Data Source is of the type XML and in other case(working report) it was Sharepoint list.The issue was because the Reporting Service was in native mode should be [configured in Integrated Mode](http://dinesql.blogspot.in/2010/06/configuring-reporting-services-2008-r2.html).

Answer (score 0):

This one is a simple one usually.

Remove reporting service and re-add it, this error is because it's config files are missing.

Comment: Do you mean to say deactivate and reactivate `Report Server Integration Feature` and  `Reporting` feature from **Site collection features**  or is it something else. Please explain what i need to do as i had not configured Reporting Service, it was just there. Kindly help

Comment: This was not the issue

Answer (score 0):

add the report viewer assembly reference in the SharePoint web application web.config file
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SharePointWebApp\

```
<add key="CustomReportView" value="Extensions.Dashboard.CustomReportView, CustomReports,    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4b493225b1eafa7" />
```

Comment: That did not work! still the same issue